# JUnit 5 test execution ordered by tag

Tags: junit, junit5

Is it possible to change the order of test execution based on `@Tag`? I want to have all the tests marked with `@Tag("fast")` executed before `@Tag("slow")`.

Im interested in solutions for IntelliJ IDEA and Maven. Both do not care about the order in which the tags are configured.

My config for Maven:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.0</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <configuration>
        <properties>
            <includeTags>fast,slow</includeTags>
        </properties>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I guess my best bet is to run the suites separately.

Answer (score 1):

JUnit Jupiter only makes a single pass over the test classes and executes all tests whose tag is active, so it does not order. For a tool to order tests by tags, it would have to run JUnit several times, once for each tag, but no tool does that out of the box.

In IntelliJ [you can run all tests with a specific tag](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-junit.html) (earch for "@Tag"), so you could generate several such configuration. In Maven you could give Surefire and Failsafe different tags to execute, although that would only buy you two executions instead of one.

Comment: In Maven you should be able to configure a _profile_ per tag for either Surefire or Failsafe, and that would allow you to group them however you want.

Comment: So configured groups are merged? Haven't tried... will do that later.

Comment: Well, they would in fact be separate runs of the JUnit Platform, but the generated test reports could be aggregated. So in the sense of the latter, yes, the overall test results would be merged -- for example, by the CI server.

Comment: To clarify: _profile per tag_ is of course possible, but activating several profiles neither leads to all tags being activated (one profile trumps the others [no, it doesn't insult them on Twitter]) nor to them being run in any specific order. It is of course possible to call Maven several times with different profiles.